# Yosemite, iOS 8 and iCloud drive: syncing mobile to desktop?

Tags: ios, icloud, osx-yosemite

I have a couple of iOS 8 apps that make use of the new iCloud Drive service and the native API for copying files to the app's personal iCloud file directory. Using two separate devices, I can upload files on one device, and download it on the other: so far so good. Now, having upgraded my macs to OS X.10 Yosemite, I have the iCloud Drive folder, but it only shows the files from the one applicable Apple product that I ever use (Keynote):

[image: iCloud Drive: rather sparse...]

The files that are happily syncing between mobile devices are nowhere to be seen; I'm pretty sure that the documentation implies that they're supposed to be there, and that the distinction between mobile & desktop folders has been taken away. If I hunt around in ~/Library/Mobile\ Devices, I can find them, so they are updating behind the scenes. Or perhaps that update happened when the computer was still running OS X.9 Mavericks.

Anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

On Yosemite it seems Finder is treating iCloud as a special folder, so it doesn't show the hidden files and folders. If you use Terminal to examine `~/Library/Mobile Documents/` it all seems to be there.

Trying to put the full pathname into Finder just dumps you back at the 'official' iCloud view, so it looks like Terminal is required in order to browse these on OS X.

Comment: I'm getting the same results. Note that I originally mentioned ~/Library/Mobile\ Devices, which is where the files got updated to before I upgraded to Yosemite. I checked ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents, and it has the most recent updates, which is interesting: it looks like even though iCloud was upgraded to "Drive" earlier, the files have been duplicated to a new location.

Comment: ... and not being able to access the files in Finder kind of defeats the purpose of having mobile & desktop apps both using cloud storage, at least for a major use case scenario anyway. I hope this isn't permanent.

Comment: I think this is more Apple trying to keep the average user away from things like private database files. Is there maybe something you need to setup in order to get access to the Mobile App's Documents/ folder? Or is this maybe a container setup with the old $TEAM_ID style identifier rather than the new icloud styled one? Or there's maybe some sort of config setting to enable this. Or the apps have to opt in to allowing their files to be seen by other apps in iCloud. I'm afraid I'm at the limit of my knowledge on this!

Comment: I'd like to make it possible for users to drag a file into the appropriate iCloud folder using Finder, and voila, it's now accessible from mobile, too. And likewise for mobile to desktop. This looks like the way it works for Apple's own products, and I want that for mine, too. If common files are only desktop sharable with custom products, but otherwise invisible, that's a great deal less compelling.

Comment: This might be helpful: [from Document Picker Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/EnablingiCloudDriveSupport/EnablingiCloudDriveSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451-CH4-SW1)

Comment: It looked promising, but adding the recommended content into the app's Info.plist and running it on mobile devices had no effect. Perhaps it won't work its magic until the latest is up on the appstore, but that seems like a bit of a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was going to System Preferences, iCloud, unchecking iCloud Drive, restarting the computer, and then repeating but this time checking iCloud Drive.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered an easy way to view the original Mobile Documents folder without the view switching to the new **iCloud Drive** view.

Access your hidden Library folder within your User folder. (for example, click the Go menu in Finder while holding down the Option key)

Then select the Mobile Documents folder and create an alias to it (by right clicking)
Now, double-click to open the alias. Presto. This opens the actual Mobile Documents folder.

You will notice that some of the folders names have changed. You will note the **iCloud Drive** folder is also present.

It may be helpful to use the terminal or another utility to unhide the hidden files in Finder.